# C# winform, progressbar with BetterListView

Tags: c#, winforms, better-listview

I'm working with BetterListView from Component Owl. in the listView there are 3 columns, Name, Time and Progress.. the user can select any item of it, if there exists in the list.

The problem is now, i want to add a progressbar into the listview item. The Question: How can i do it, with the BetterListView from Component Owl?! I found nothing in the description to do it.

Comment: I have tried to add the progress bar into the listview item, but there is no way to do this. I have only see this feature in the sample application and in the video.